# Algorithm for concave but not-self-intersecting polygon union

Tags: algorithm, 2d, union, polygon

I have two arrays:

var polygon1: [CGPoint] = []
var polygon2: [CGPoint] = []

I have captured the following points on a 2d plane in the arrays respectfully:
polygon1:

(175.5,225.5)
(140.0,200.5)
(130.5,194.0)
(129.5,192.0)
(148.5,184.5)
(182.5,174.0)
(186.0,176.5)
(175.5,225.5)

polygon2:

(141.5,225.0)
(141.5,218.5)
(141.5,178.0)
(140.0,149.0)
(155.5,151.0)
(172.5,164.5)
(163.0,192.5)
(141.5,225.0)

I would like to combine the polygons. The polygons can be concave, without holes and never self-intersecting. Which algorithm should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try alpha shapes. Basically it a delaunay triangulation without edges exceeding alpha.  You can also traverse the convex hull of the triangulation and use a point in polygon test, for example with the rays method.